# Using redirect_to without a path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just learning Rails from a text book and here is a code I saw in the book:

```
redirect_to @line_item.cart
```

But so far I was used to see something like `redirect to line_item_path`

So is it a new Rails syntax for redirect_to?  does it automatically generate the path? Could we rewrite it with _path in it too?

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it with the path, but there is little point. Is `cart` an association of the line_item or an attribute of the `line_item`? Typically, your `redirect_to @line_item` will take you to the show action of the `@line_item`. However, if in your models you have something called cart and it `belongs_to :line_item` then `redirect_to @line_item.cart` will take the user to the show action of the `cart`. You may want to be careful if a `line_item` does not have a `cart` assigned as you will get an error.